# IIS URL Authorization with AD Domain Group ( security group type vs distribution group type)

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, active-directory, authorization

I was trying to configure the IIS URL authorization rules for AD domain accounts, and found that it works fine with accounts and security group types but not with distribution group type. Is it similar to ACL's which cant be applied on Distribution group types ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* difference between distribution groups and security groups is that distribution groups cannot be used for authorization.

When someone logs in, their [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-tokens) contains a list of every security group they are in (recursively, so if one group is a member of another group, both groups are listed). Distribution groups are not included in that list.

The URL authorization rules use the user's access token to see if the user is a member of the group, so it will not work with distribution groups.